# Conversão de nome de arquivos de epoch timestamp para data

Tags: bash, shell-script

Caros;

Tenho uma lista de arquivos (140 mil) com data no formato [Unix epoch timestamp](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix) no nome do arquivo. Preciso converter cada arquivo para corresponder a data real dele, alterando seu nome. Exemplo: 1475279740.15044_xxx.xxx.stats, onde o epoch timestamp é 1475279740, convertendo dá 2016-09-30 (2016-09-30_xxx.xxx.stats).

Tenho a lista de arquivos com seus nomes em timestamp e outro arquivo com a lista de nomes já convertida, ambas em *txt*. Porém, preciso alterar/mover o arquivo que contém o timestamp para os arquivos convertidos.

Imagino ter dois `for` onde um abre a lista de arquivos timestamp e outro `for` que abre os arquivos convertidos e após seria só alterar/mover com um simples comando `mv`.

Para testar, criei estes dois laços `for`, porém apenas a segunda variável é alterada em sequência, a primeira fica estática.

Segue o código de exemplo:

```
 for x in $(cat timestamp.txt)
     do
         for y in $(cat timestamp-conv.txt)
       do

           echo $x convertido para $y

    done
 done
```

Saída esperada do código:

```
  1474566212 convertido para 2016-09-24
  1474566212 convertido para 2016-09-24
  1474566212 convertido para 2016-09-24
  1474566212 convertido para 2016-09-24
  1474566212 convertido para 2016-09-24
  1474566212 convertido para 2016-09-24
  1474566212 convertido para 2016-09-24
  1474566212 convertido para 2016-09-24
  1474566212 convertido para 2016-09-24
  1474566212 convertido para 2016-09-24
  1474566212 convertido para 2016-09-24
  1474566212 convertido para 2016-09-25
  1474566212 convertido para 2016-09-25
```

As duas listas estão idênticas, linha por linha entre as duas batem o timestamp com o outro já convertido.

Já tentei de varias formas, sem sucesso!

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: E a hora, tu não vai precisar? É possível que dois arquivos tenham a mesma data, daí o que os diferenciaria seria a hora.

Comment: Não é necessário a hora, só a data mesmo.

Comment: A lista com o nome dos arquivos está em `timestemp.txt`? Um por linha? Tu quer copiar o arquivo `1475279740.15044_xxx.xxx.stats` para o arquivo `2016-09-30_xxx.xxx.stats`, por exemplo, e imprimir um relatório no final de todos os arquivos convertidos, é isso?

Comment: Tenho um diretorio com 140 mil arquivos de logs.Cada arquivo de Log está com timestamp do dia que foi salvo. Então destes 140 mil arquivos, tenho arquivo de setembro a outrubro. Como o script que faz isso diariamente deu pau, só vimos depois de quase dois meses, teremos que filtrar cada arquivo por sua data atual em timestamp, convertendo de timestamp para a data real e salvar em um diretorio com esta data. Então, preciso saber os dias de todos arquivos para fazer esta conversao: de 1475279740.15044_xxx.xxx.stats para 2016-09-30_xxx.xxx.stats. Não sei se ficou claro, caso não desculpe !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que este script possa fazer o trabalho:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3< timestamp.txt

while read arq <&3; do
    epoch=$(echo $arq | awk '{ print $1 }' FS="_")
    filenameend=$(echo $arq | awk '{ print $2 }' FS="_")
    date=$(date --date="@$epoch" +%Y-%m-%d)
    mv ${arq} ${date}_${filenameend} && echo ${arq} convertido para ${date}_${filenameend}
done

exec 3<&-
```

Comment: Você disse que não precisa diferenciar pela hora, então vais perder arquivos se tiveres mais de um no mesmo dia: o último da lista sobrescreverá o(s) anterior(es). Cuidado com isso!

Comment: Olá Thiago, na verdade, quando eu ter a certeza que estiver funcionando, eu irei adicionar no final de cada arquivo convertido uma string para diferenciar, por isso eu estava usando o echo. O que me interessa é o conteúdo de cada arquivo, e não o nome dele. Me tira uma duvida, vc setou em seu While o arquivo timestemp.txt. Onde entra o outro arquivo convertido? Ou seu codigo irá converter na hora os arquivos sem a necessidade de um arquivo secundário? Grato pelo seu interesse em ajudar.

Comment: Então, ele já move o arquivo original para o novo arquivo, com a data formatada como tu querias. Não existe a necessidade de criar mais um arquivo para controlar a conversão de nomes.

Comment: Grande Thiago, irei testar seu código. Grande abraço!

Comment: Ok! Depois dê o feedback aqui com o upvote ou alguma dúvida que tenhas para ajudar os outros que tiverem o mesmo problema.

Comment: Opa TIago, deu certo, testei e funcionou do modo esperado. Agradeço! Aproveitando, tenho algumas duvidas em relação ao seu codigo para meu aprendizado. Este serve como delimitador (FS="_") ? Para que serve este comando <&3 ? .

Comment: O `FS="_"` serve como a definição do delimitador para o comando `awk`, conforme tu supôs! Então quando direcionamos a saída do comando `echo $arq` pro `awk`, o mesmo separa em strings pelo separador definido. Logo, passando o comando `{ print $2}` na sequencia estamos nos referindo à segunda string, ou a string logo após o primeiro "_" (separador).

Comment: O comando `exec 3< timestamp.txt` vai criar um novo _file descriptor_ e vincular o arquivo timestamp.txt à ele. Isso tem a ver com teu requisito, que é de processar um grande número de linhas do arquivo `timestamp.txt`. Caso não fizesse assim, carregaríamos o arquivo todo em memória e pode haver um prejuízo de desempenho do teu script. Assim, usando um file descriptor, as linhas do arquivo podem ser lidas uma a uma e processadas da mesma forma, isso é o que acontece no comando `read arq <&3`. Existem outras soluções, essa é só uma delas. As outras soluções envolvem usar o comando `xargs`.

Comment: Alguns comandos Linux também podem não aceitar uma lista de argumentos muito grande e pode ser necessária uma solução deste tipo, usando `xargs` ou _file descriptors_. Espero ter esclarecido tuas dúvidas!

Comment: Pohhh é isso mesmo Thiago, as vezes me deparo com List too long e tenho que fazer algumas gambiarras para funcionar, porem nunca soube de uma resposta/solução para este caso. Esse (FS="_"), é a mesma coisa de usar o cut com delimitador " _ " ? . Com sua explicação, já ficou mais claro. Obrigado e grande abraço.

Comment: Sim, o FS é o delimitador  ;-)